# Prevent overflow in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, siunitx

I have a list of figures where, when using `siunitx`, the value and units do not separate onto new lines and so overflow the margin of the list of figures (see below).

[image]

I can (and have) crudely solved the issue by splitting `\SI` into `\num` and `\si`, however was wondering if there is a "nicer" solution which automatically typesets the list so that it doesn't overflow? Better yet would be one that prevents the overflow while keeping the units with the number.

EDIT: Latex code as requested

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} %12pt font

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage[final]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font={small},labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %1.5 line spacing
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[detect-weight=true,detect-family=true,separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue, breaklinks=true}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{alongshore_WS}
\caption{Annually-smoothed alongshore wind stress (\si{N.m^{-2}}) calculated over the region enclosed by 44--46\si{\degree} S, with zonal boundaries at 165--166.45\si{\degree} E in the south and 165--168.53\si{\degree} E in the north, over the altimeter record (April 1993 -- November 2016). The dashed line is the linear trend over this time period (\SI{1.31 +- 1.60E-3}{N.m^{-2}.decade^{-1}}). A negative wind stress represents wind flowing down the coast (i.e. poleward).}
\label{fig:WS}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I‘d never include, in full, a caption that long in the list of figures: I’d rather use the optional argument of the `\caption` command to provide an alternative, and *much* shorter, caption.

Comment: @GuM fair point. However, hypothetically speaking, if I still had this issue in a shorter comment what would be your recommended way of fixing it?

Comment: Interpolating lengthy in-line math expressions in text that is going to be paragraphed usually makes for though line-breaking problems: there is no easy fix for them, and very often the only viable solution is, alas, to rephrase the text to fit… :-(

Comment: @GuM good to know. Fortunately shortening the caption does solve the problem here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In this case the only sensible point of fracture seems to be the `\times` sign (more precisely, to break the line *after* it); but TeX already knows that, has already considered this solution, but has rejected it because it doesn’t satisfy its high standards nonetheless.  Reporting an `Overfull \hbox` is actually TeX’s way of drawing your attention to a line that simply cannot be typeset in any acceptable way, and to prompt you to rewrite the passage so as to make the problem vanish.

Comment: There is also `\sisetup{allow-number-unit-breaks=true}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have adequately solved this problem for me so I thought I'd summarise the two solutions here in case others have a similar issue.

1) Firstly, as **GuM** points out, a figure caption in a list of figures section should be shorter than what I have in the question. Therefore the best solution in my case was to shorten the figure caption, i.e. `\caption[Shorter caption]{Extended caption}`.

2) However, if this does not solve the problem (and the list of figures still overflows) then using `\sisetup{allow-number-unit-breaks=true}` as suggested by **John Kormylo** also works. Note that this can also be included when reading the package in `\usepackage[allow-number-unit-breaks=true]{siunitx}`.